# Magento site in between getting disconnected , becomes slow.. Why?

Tags: magento-1.7

Actually my site has so many api's like betaout, flipkart, amazon and so on. Now it has become very big site. I want to increase site speed as well as want to know the reason why it is gettting disconnected and becomes slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your site has many APIs, chances are that it is making many external requests which will undoubtedly slow it down. Additionally, if you are on a shared hosting environment, that almost always slows a Magento site down when there are more that a handful of users on it at one time.

You should also check your php.ini and .htaccess files and make sure that you have ample memory allocated to your site.

Comment: sorry I am late to reply. Thanks for your reply.  Can you give some suggestion that what should I do to get a better result?

Comment: [use full cache](https://github.com/lalitmohann/Lesti_Fpc)

Comment: @latit that's might help but it's not a solution. If your server can't handle magneto, full page cache will just help a little but not fix the problem.